# tastypie - how to Filter Generic Foreign Key?

Tags: django, django-models, filter, tastypie

I have this as my resource

```
class AResource(ModelResource):
    content_object = GenericForeignKeyField({
        B: BResource,
    }, 'content_object')

class Meta:
    queryset = A.objects.all()
    filtering = {
        'content_type': ????,
    }
```

I want to filter this resource by id of resource BResource. 
I try to filter by this url: 

http://domain.com/api/v1/a/?content_type=/api/v1/b/7/

and http://domain.com/api/v1/a/?content_object=/api/v1/b/7/

 but it didn't work.

How can we filter this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an older question, but in case anyone else finds it, I was able to solve this same problem by doing the following:

```
filtering = {
    'object_id': 'exact',
    'content_type': 'exact',
}
```

Then your resource url would look like:

```
http://domain.com/api/v1/a/?content_type=app_name,model_name&object_id=object_id
```

so in the case of the OP, assuming BResource is in myapp and the model name is b_model

```
http://domain.com/api/v1/a/?content_type=myapp,b_model&object_id=7
```